# How can I match reference-style markdown links?

Tags: javascript

I am interested in using Javascript to find all reference-style markdown links in a string of text. So I would want the following:

- `[all the things][things] => "things"`
- `[something] => "something"`

But not:

- `[o hai](http://example.com)`
- `[o hai] (http://example.com)`

In other words, an open square bracket followed by a close square bracket, capturing the text inside, but not the same followed by a set of parentheses.

Make sense? Thanks!

Comment: make sense for whom?  How can you do this without showing code.

Comment: Well, for anyone. The ground rules are Javascript and use case. There is no code yet. I'm interested in knowing what options are available for doing something like this.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
/(?:\[[\w\s]*\])?(\[[\w\s]*\])(?!\s*\()/
 ^--------------^ - possibly first [...], ?: - non-capturing group
                 ^-----------^ - followed by [...]
                              ^-------^ - not followed by "   (" - spaces + (

> [all the things][things]".match(/(?:\[[\w\s]*\])?(\[[\w\s]*\])(?!\s*\()/)[1]
"[things]"
> "[something]".match(/(?:\[[\w\s]*\])?(\[[\w\s]*\])(?!\s*\()/)[1]
"[something]"
> "[o hai](http://example.com)".match(/(?:\[[\w\s]*\])?(\[[\w\s]*\])(?!\s*\()/)
null
> "[o hai] (http://example.com)".match(/(?:\[[\w\s]*\])?(\[[\w\s]*\])(?!\s*\()/)
null
```